# Error in moving the file, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, file-io

```
File file = new File(FILE_DIR);
    File[] files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
     }
    });
```

Below i am looping through the directory, SO that i can move one file to another directory

```
for (File name : files) {
    int i = 1;
    System.out.println("PDF present in folder  " + i + ".  " + name.getName());
    Path temp = Files.move(Paths.get(FILE_DIR + name.getName()),
                    Paths.get(LocalFilePathSuccess + name.getName()));

   if (temp != null) {
       System.out.println("File renamed and moved successfully");
   } else {
       System.out.println("Failed to move the file");
   }
```

But when i am running the code i am getting the following error as
**

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ---> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.
>   **

From this error i came to know that, the particular file is being under process that's why we cant move it.

What i want is that,
How can i stop this file process and then move the file.

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: I think the file is open.

Comment: That is mentioned in the question itself sir... I want how can i CLOSE that FILE, so i can move it to another folder...